# Crontab does not work properly in Ubuntu

Tags: cron

I am learning how to use cron. I wrote some simple code in my crontab

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/1 * * * * echo "1 minute"> ~/Document/cronoutput
```

I expected it to print the words every minute, but it does not. Then I check [a page](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it). I run the following command

```
ps -ef | grep cron | grep -v grep
```

it returns

```
root     21430     1  0 13:24 ?        00:00:00 cron
```

after a few second, I rerun the command again:

```
root     21430     1  0 13:24 ?        00:00:00 cron
```

I suppose cron does not count elapsed time since it always shows 00:00.

What may be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: does the command work from the command line?

Comment: The time here is the amount of CPU time used by the cron process. Since cron requires a negligible amount of CPU time, it'll stay at 0 for a while. This is normal. Have you set up local email? If a command fails, you'll receive an email to your local account, but some OSes don't set up local email by default or don't show them to you.

Answer (score 1):

You've got it half right, but your syntax is incorrect.  To run a cronjob every minute, enter asterisks in every field

```
# m h dom mon dow   command
  * * * * * echo "1 minute"> ~/Document/cronoutput
```

If you look in your `syslog` logs you'll probably see an error along the lines of `syntax error: this crontab will be ignored`

The syntax you're using works, just not for every minute.

#### Every 2 hours

```
# m h dom mon dow   command    
  0 */2 * * * /path-to-script
```

#### Every 2 days

```
# m h dom mon dow   command
  0 0 */2 * * /path-to-script
```

#### Every 2 months

```
# m h dom mon dow   command
  0 0 0 */2 * /path-to-script
```

Comment: What syntax error do you see?

Comment: */1 for every minute vs. just an *

Comment: But that's not wrong, it's just an overly verbose synonym.

Answer (score -1):

Try out same in `/tmp` directory, it must work:

```
*/1 * * * * echo "1 minute" > /tmp/cronoutput
```

If you try command from commandline, it will deny you with the permission problem.